# Forwarding Outlook Emails to Multiple Recipients

Tags: vba, outlook

How do I add multiple email addresses to the myForward.Recipients.Add bit? I've tried adding them like that **`"test@test.com; test1@test.com; test2@test.com",`**

But only the first one receives the message.

```
Sub ChangeSubjectForward(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Item.Subject = "Test"
 Item.Save

Set myForward = Item.Forward
myForward.Recipients.Add "test@test.com"

myForward.Send

End Sub
```

Comment: Can't do `myForward.Recipients.Add "test@test.com"` and `myForward.Recipients.Add "test1@test.com"` and `myForward.Recipients.Add "test2@test.com"`? Should be able to just add more lines with recipients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding  the following line for each recipient

```
myForward.Recipients.Add "test1@test.com"

myForward.Recipients.Add "test2@test.com"

myForward.Recipients.Add "test3@test.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

Or set the `Mailtem.To` property to a ";" separated list of addresses.